# Two dimensional function not returning array of values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to plot a 2-dimensional function (specifically, a 2-d Laplace solution). I defined my function and it returns the right value when I put in specific numbers, but when I try running through an array of values (x,y below), it still returns only one number. I tried with a random function of x and y (e.g., f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2) and it gives me an array of values.

```
def V_func(x,y):
    a = 5
    b = 4
    Vo = 4
    n = np.arange(1,100,2)
    sum_list = []

    for indx in range(len(n)):
        sum_term = (1/n[indx])*(np.cosh(n[indx]*np.pi*x/a))/(np.cosh(n[indx]*np.pi*b/a))*np.sin(n[indx]*np.pi*y/a)
        sum_list = np.append(sum_list,sum_term)

    summation = np.sum(sum_list)
    V = 4*Vo/np.pi * summation

    return V

x = np.linspace(-4,4,50)
y = np.linspace(0,5,50)
V_func(x,y)
```

Out: 53.633709914177224

Comment: `sum_list` starts as a list `[]`.  `sum_term` looks like it would produce an array the same size as `x` and `y`.  Then you append this to `sum_list` using `np.append` (why not `sum_list.append`?).  So `sum_list` ends up a 1d array (read the `np.append` docs).  Then you `np.sum` that reducing it to one number (read its docs).  It isn't clear where the 2d is supposed to come from?  From `x`, `y`, `n` or some outer product?

Comment: From x and y, the summation is just a part of the function. Basically, I want to get a single number as an outcome but when I input an array, I'd like for it to return an array. For example, if the function z = x**2 + y**2 was given the same values for x and y as above, it returns an array.

Comment: does that simpler function produce a 1d or 2d array?

Comment: 1d, then I used the meshgrid function to get a 2d array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def V_func(x,y):
  a = 5
  b = 4
  Vo = 4
  n = np.arange(1,100,2)
  # sum_list = []
  sum_list = np.zeros(50)

  for indx in range(len(n)):
      sum_term = (1/n[indx])*(np.cosh(n[indx]*np.pi*x/a))/(np.cosh(n[indx]*np.pi*b/a))*np.sin(n[indx]*np.pi*y/a)
      # sum_list = np.append(sum_list,sum_term)
      sum_list += sum_term

  # summation = np.sum(sum_list)
  # V = 4*Vo/np.pi * summation
  V = 4*Vo/np.pi * sum_list

  return V
```

Comment: When I do that, I end up with an array of 2500 instead of 50. I'm having trouble incorporating the summation of terms for n=1,3,5... in the function.

Comment: Wow, I see now! Thanks so much, I guess np.sum was messing up the output.

Answer (score 0):

Define a pair of arrays:

```
In [6]: x = np.arange(3); y = np.arange(10,13)
In [7]: x,y
Out[7]: (array([0, 1, 2]), array([10, 11, 12]))
```

Try a simple function of the 2

```
In [8]: x + y
Out[8]: array([10, 12, 14])
```

Since they have the same size, they can be summed (or otherwise combined) elementwise.  The result has the same shape as the 2 inputs.

Now try 'broadcasting'.  `x[:,None]` has shape (3,1)

```
In [9]: x[:,None] + y
Out[9]: 
array([[10, 11, 12],
       [11, 12, 13],
       [12, 13, 14]])
```

The result is (3,3), the first 3 from the reshaped `x`, the second from `y`.

I can generate the pair of arrays with `meshgrid`:

```
In [10]: I,J = np.meshgrid(x,y,sparse=True, indexing='ij')
In [11]: I
Out[11]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
In [12]: J
Out[12]: array([[10, 11, 12]])
In [13]: I + J
Out[13]: 
array([[10, 11, 12],
       [11, 12, 13],
       [12, 13, 14]])
```

Note the added parameters in `meshgrid`.  So that's how we go about generating 2d values from a pair of 1d arrays.

Now look at what `sum` does.  As you use it in the function:

```
In [14]: np.sum(I + J)
Out[14]: 108
```

the result is a scalar.  See the docs.  If I specify an `axis` I get an array.

```
In [15]: np.sum(I + J, axis=0)
Out[15]: array([33, 36, 39])
```

If you gave `V_func` the right `x` and `y`, `sum_list` could be a 3d array.  That axis-less `sum` reduces it to a scalar.

In code like this you need to keep track of array shapes.  Include test prints if needed; don't just assume anything; test it.  Pay attention to how dimensions grow and shrink as they pass through various operations.

Comment: Thanks so much, I figured it out.